# IntelliJ IDEA: How can I write SQL comments without it inserting a concatenation operator?

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea

I write my database `DDL` as Flyway scripts in `.sql` files, which IDEA understands quite well.  I have the Postgres dialect selected in IDEA so it fully understands all the keywords and functions and specialities of Postgres SQL.

Except database comment objects - as opposed to SQL comments, which it understands fine.

Whenever I try to write a multi-line comment object, IDEA gets confused and tries to insert the concatenation operator - `||`.

So if I write this and the cursor is left inside the quotes (because IDEA auto-completes the string):

```
comment on column table_x.column_y is 'first line'
```

Then press enter, IDEA gets tries to be helpful by updating the code to:

```
comment on column table_x.table_y is 'first line' ||
  ''
```

But that SQL is invalid, you can't use the concatenation operator there (postgres will give `syntax error at or near "||"`).

A multi-line Postgres comment needs to be either this, which results in concatenation of the comment string:

```
comment on column table_x.table_y is 'first line' 
  'second line'
```

or this, which results in embedded new lines:

```
comment on column table_x.table_y is 'first line
second line'
```

I tried turning off the SQL intention `Split string literal` but it didn't seem to change this behaviour.

Is there any option in IDEA that I can change to have it not interfere when writing multi-line comment objects?

**EDIT:**
IDEA version is 2018.3.3
There's nothing relevant in the idea.log file.
[Issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-7716) now exists for the problem.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Shorn, Can you pls provide your IntelliJ version and a screenshot of your sql window.

Comment: Works fine on my machine. Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn **Insert string concatenation on Enter** off[image]